# sql-select rows based on input count variable and update column in the returned rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I'm missing something simple here and would appreciate some help.

I am passing a JobId and count variable to sql. I need to retrieve the number of rows where the JobId = @JobId, JobFilledDate is null and the number of records returned is equal to or less than the count variable @CntFilled. I then need to update the jobpeningdate for each record.

My sql is returning all records matching jobid and jobfilleddate=null instead of the count variable.

```
 @JobId int,
 @CntFilled int

AS
DECLARE @FillId int

SELECT @FillId = JobOpeningId 
FROM tbJobOpening
WHERE JobId = @JobId
      AND JobOpeningFilledDate is NULL
GROUP BY JobOpeningId
HAVING COUNT(*)<=@CntFilled

UPDATE tbJobOpening
SET JobOpeningFilledDate=getDate()
WHERE JobOpeningId = @FillId
```

Comment: it would help if you can add some sample data along with your desired output

Comment: I think you want `select top @CntFilled` rather than the `having` clause, but it is hard to say without sample data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're @FillId is a single variable and the select is unlikely to bring back just a single record to populate @FillId which would cause unexpected results. I would have thought that this is more appropriate...

```
SELECT JobOpeningId
into #temp_jobids
FROM tbJobOpening
WHERE JobId = @JobId
  AND JobOpeningFilledDate is NULL
GROUP BY JobOpeningId
HAVING COUNT(*)<=@CntFilled

UPDATE jo
SET JobOpeningFilledDate=getDate()
FROM tbJobOpening jo
INNER JOIN #temp_jobids tjo on jo.JobOpeningId = tjo.JobOpeningId

drop table #temp_jobids
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to save the IDs? Do you use them later?
If not, you can update your records without any temporary tables:

```
UPDATE
    tbJobOpening
SET
    JobOpeningFilledDate = GETDATE()
WHERE
    JobOpeningId IN (
        SELECT
            JobOpeningId 
        FROM
            tbJobOpening
        WHERE
            JobId = @JobId
            AND JobOpeningFilledDate is NULL
        GROUP BY
            JobOpeningId
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) <= @CntFilled
    )
    AND JobOpeningFilledDate IS NULL -- Optional, you can remove this if you want to update ALL records!
```